# Native MC identifiers in Flash AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm not certain how to word the question but hopefully my description will make things clear.

I have a movieClip with hundreds of smaller clips, much like a map.  I want to name clips based on their type using a letter system.  Type "e" = editable and type "i" = icon.

I have a script that will enumerate through all the children of my parent MC and determine the types of each one ("e" or "i") but from that point I don't have a way to retain which ones are which.  If I were to apply some formatting to an object dynamically like height, width and color and store that in a Database, upon reload how do I determine which one they were applied to?  I can't use x and y coordinates because these elements can be moved as well.

Also assume that I can't use a convention like "e1", "e2", "e3" - etc.  We're using this method now and it results in constant duplication of numbers due to the maps being hundreds of elements large.

I'm looking for a native identifier to flash.  Possibly an undocumented property.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why can't the parent display object just assign an identifier property on the base class and create a reference map when it is looping through the children?

Flash will also auto assign an instance name to all display objects if you don't specify one.  The parent container can then save them off and use getChildByName().

Comment: That doesn't directly answer the question but it DOES provide a different way of solving the problem.  By grouping them all in a parent "e" class I can then use the auto-assigned Flash instance names to reference them later.

Comment: I am assigning them all a name of either "e" or "i".

Comment: I'm glad this got you going in the right direction.  Base classes on display objects, even if they don't really extend the parent class, can come in really handy.